# Specify SQL Server instanceName in WebSphere 7

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, websphere, datasource

I have this SQL Server Database with two instances and I'm trying to create a connection pool in WAS7 but I don't know how to specify the instance name.

I've tried using the "custom properties" tab and fill the "instanceName"  section but I don't see the difference, no matter what I put there the query always to the same instance ( I guess that's the default instance ).

How can I specify the connection properties?

Can someone point me in the right direction?
[image: shalala]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what WAS7 is. Instance name is the one you have specified during the SQL Server instance installation. The default instance name is MSSQLSERVER, other than that is named instance name.

To find the instance name, you can check it in the SQL Server Configuration Manager, or run the following query in the SSMS: SELECT @@SERVICENAME.

Any more help needed, please let us know.

Comment: WAS7 stands for "WebSphere Application Server v7.0.01"